# Implementation of TextRank algorithm using Spark(Calculating cosine similarity matrix using spark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, nlp, textrank

I am trying to implement textrank algorithm where I am calculating cosine-similarity matrix for all the sentences.I want to parallelize the task of similarity matrix creation using Spark but don't know how to implement it.Here is the code:

```
    cluster_summary_dict = {}
    for cluster,sentences in tqdm(cluster_wise_sen.items()):
        sen_sim_matrix = np.zeros([len(sentences),len(sentences)])
        for row in range(len(sentences)):
            for col in range(len(sentences)):
                if row != col:
                    sen_sim_matrix[row][col] = cosine_similarity(cluster_dict[cluster]  
                                               [row].reshape(1,100), cluster_dict[cluster] 
                                               [col].reshape(1,100))[0,0]
        sentence_graph = nx.from_numpy_array(sen_sim_matrix)
        scores = nx.pagerank(sentence_graph) 
        pagerank_sentences = sorted(((scores[k],sent) for k,sent in enumerate(sentences)), 
                             reverse=True)
        cluster_summary_dict[cluster] = pagerank_sentences
```

Here,cluster_wise_sen is a dictionary that contains list of sentences for different clusters ({'cluster 1' : [list of sentences] ,...., 'cluster n' : [list of sentences]}). cluster_dict contains the 100d vector representation of the sentences. I have to compute the sentence similarity matrix for each cluster. Since it is time consuming, therefore looking to parallelize it using spark.

Comment: Are you looking exclusively on using spark or do you want to parallelize whatever the technical solution?

Comment: I can use other method also. It need not necessarily be Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The experiments with large scale matrix calculation for cosine similarity are well written in [here](https://medium.com/@rantav/large-scale-matrix-multiplication-with-pyspark-or-how-to-match-two-large-datasets-of-company-1be4b1b2871e)!

To achieve speed and not compromising much on the accuracy, you can also try hashing methods like Min-Hash and evaluate Jaccard Distance similarity. It comes with a nice implementation with Spark ML-lib, the documentation has very detailed examples for reference: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#minhash-for-jaccard-distance

Comment: Great - Which method did you implement?

Comment: The first link.